# Ember JS custom request from model data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to send a custom request to an api via EmberJS, now the url will be something like

```
> http://host/stats
```

I need to pass 4 parameters

coulmns, dateColumn, startDate, endDate

so the request will be something along the lines of

```
> http://host/stats?columns=cost&dateColumn=date&startDate=2013-12-12&endDate=2013-12-12
```

I have a model already made that has those 4 values, so I just have to create a record with the values and pass those values, the question is, how do I pass them values?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ember Data?  Or just raw ajax calls?

Comment: @kingpin2k for this it will be just raw ajax, but I'm using ember data to store the request values.

Comment: Where are you firing from, button on a page, model hook?

Comment: @kingpin2k well it will be both really, it will load as soon as the page loads, and if things are changed then it will load it again with an action, so far I haven't really done either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/ this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
model: function(){
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://host/stats",
      data: { columns: "cost", dateColumn: ...}
    })
}
```

You may want to use query params as Mengu mentioned, depends on your workflow